# Jquery Checkbox not changing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

the issues is that if you check and then uncheck the vacancy_select checkbox, then check the selection checkbox it doesn't change the vacancy_select check status

I have a few checkboxes on screen, the first checkbox `$("input[type=checkbox]#selection")` will toggle all other checkboxes, on or off depending on the status of the first checkbox.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]#selection').on('change', function () {
    let rows = $("tr.content_list > td > input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select");
    for(let i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
        $(rows[i]).attr('checked', this.checked);
    }
});
```

if, I select or change the status of any of the other checkboxes then these checkboxes

`$("tr.content_list > td > input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select")` don't updated when marking this `$("input[type=checkbox]#selection")` checkbox as checked.

[image: checkboxes]

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]#selection').on('change', function() {
  let rows = $("input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select");
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    $(rows[i]).attr('checked', this.checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  id="list_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="selection" name="selection">Selection
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="na">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ asset('/dashboard/vacancy/add')}}" style="color: #FFF">New Vacancy</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="content_list">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="{{ $vacancy->id }}">
       </td>
    </tr>a
    <tr class="content_list">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="{{ $vacancy->id }}">
       </td>
    </tr>a
    <tr class="content_list">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="{{ $vacancy->id }}">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add your full code if possible to help better way along with html

Comment: Please share all related HTML markup also.

Comment: Without html this is difficult to answer, but as a point I think you need to add single quotation around the checkbox select, i.e. $('input[type='checkbox']#selection')

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/34svpuk6/

Comment: The demo is working since it has no table, rows or cells.. but it is not same as your actual scenario. Please create a demo based your HTML markup.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/34svpuk6/1/

Comment: the issues is that if you check and then uncheck the vacancy_select checkbox, then check the selection checkbox it doesn't change the vacancy_select  check status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) for this, also  you don't need for loop to set the attribute/prop: here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/cykgnst4/3/) and a working snippet:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]#selection').on('change', function() {
  let rows = $("input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select");
  rows.prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select').on('change', function() {
  let selectedRows = $("input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select:checked").length;
  let allElements = $('input[type=checkbox].vacancy_select').length;
  let checked = false;
  if(selectedRows === allElements) {
    checked = true;
  }
  $('input[type=checkbox]#selection').prop('checked', checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selection" name="selection">Selection

<input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="vacancy_select" data-vacancy-id="4">
```

Comment: If all the checkboxes are checked individually, the selection checkbox will not get checked as it should

Comment: I just add to use `prop` as `attr` returns the default value, and that prop returns the current value, thanks man. web tech changing all the time... so you know how it goes

Comment: Glad to help, yes it is changing and we need to keep updated with whats going on, every few days there is something new :)